# Defining a funtion to use BeautifulSoup to find the table title and table. Then append table title to each table row

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following function that takes in a url and finds the first table and its rows (`tr`):

```
def get_team_table(url):
  page = urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
  data_rows = [row for row in soup.find("table", "datatable").find_all("tr")]
  return data_rows
```

The function is used below to pull the table rows from tables present in each url. `links_all` is the list of urls to iterate over, and the output from the function is appended to `team_data`.

```
team_data = []

for link in links_all:
  team_data.append(get_team_table(link))
```

However, I would also like to the pull the title (`title` tag) of the table as well. And I would like to have each `title` as a list item that comes immediately before each `tr` list item. This code doesn't work, but it might make my idea more clear.

```
def get_team_table(url):
  page = urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
  table_title = [row for row in soup.find("title")]
  return table_title
  data_rows = [row for row in soup.find("table", "datatable").find_all("tr")]
  return data_rows
```

Once this is done, I'd like to append each table title to each row of table data. I have code that finds all `td` tags and appends to a new list. So is there a way to add onto this so that the table title and table data could be added as a single list item in table_data.

```
table_data = []
#A nested for loop because inner items of the list are BeautifulSoup Elements
for rows in team_data:
  for row in rows:
    if soup.find_all("td", class_ = "right xs-hide") is not None:
      table_data.append(row.get_text())
```

An example of a single list item looks like this:

```
\nPeterson\nPatrick Peterson\n\nCB\n$12,050,000\n-\n$250,000\n-\n$250,000\n$634,588\n-\n($13,184,588)\n$13,184,588 \n6.71\n
```

But I'm hoping with the additional of the table title, that the result would look like:

```
\nArizona Cardinals 2020 Salary Cap\nPeterson\nPatrick Peterson\n\nCB\n$12,050,000\n-\n$250,000\n-\n$250,000\n$634,588\n-\n($13,184,588)\n$13,184,588 \n6.71\n
```

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/arizona-cardinals/cap/2020/. This is just a single page, but the rest of my code is designed to iterate over 128 URLs of the same layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can read the table title with `.find_previous()` method:

```py
url = "https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/arizona-cardinals/cap/2020/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


def read_table(t):
    all_rows = []
    for row in t.select("tr:has(td)"):
        tds = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=", ") for td in row.select("td")]
        all_rows.append(tds)
    return all_rows


for table in soup.select("table.datatable"):
    title = table.find_previous(["h1", "h2"])
    title = title.text if title else "-"

    rows = read_table(table)
    print(title)

    # print only first row
    print(*rows[0], sep="\t")

    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Cardinals 2020 Salary Cap
Peterson, Patrick Peterson      CB      $12,050,000     -       $250,000        -       $250,000        $634,588        -       ($13,184,588)   $13,184,588     6.71
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020 Exempt/Commissioner’s Permission List
Gilbert, Marcus Gilbert, (COVID-19)     RT      -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       0.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020 Injured Reserve Cap
Jones, Chandler Jones, (Biceps) OLB     $16,000,000     $3,000,000      -       -       -       $2,333,333      -       ($26,666,667)   $21,333,333     10.86
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020 Practice Squad
Amukamara, Prince Amukamara     CB      $144,000        -       -       -       -       -       -       -       $144,000        0.07
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020 Dead Cap
Johnson, David Johnson  RB      -       $6,000,000      -       -       -       -       -       -       $6,000,000      3.05
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020 Cap Totals
2020 NFL Salary Cap                                                             $198,200,000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The output contains more tables than I need - I just need the first table in each URL. But the title and data in the first table are right! So this might be something I can work with. I'll come back once I've worked find_previous() into my code.

Comment: @ElphiusMostafa Then just discard the for loop. The important part is the `table.find_previous()`

Comment: I ended up being able to add find_previous() into the get_team_table() function. Thanks for the rec!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function I ended up using:

```
def get_team_table(url):
  page = urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
  title = [table for table in soup.find("table", "datatable").find_previous("title")]
  data_rows = [row for row in soup.find("table", "datatable").find_all("tr")]
  return title + data_rows
```

And the function is later used:

```
team_data = []

for link in links_all:
  team_data.append(get_team_table(link))
```

The result is one list item that places the title immediately before the `tr` tag.